# How to parse \n in string while passing the value to javascript

Tags: javascript, rhomobile, rhodes

In my code, i need to pass the value present in instance variable to javascript, and then use that value to set onto textarea.

```
$('textarea.myclass').val('<%= @text_value %>');
```

But if the variable `@text_value` contains `\n` (this is\n demo) then, its leads to javascript error and the page shows exactly as this, separated by space in between,

```
$('textarea.myclass').val('this is 
   // error message over here 
demo');
```

Any way i can handle this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also faced such situation, and i just escaped the `\` to `\\`, so finally `\n` to `\\n`, `\r` to `\\r`

```
$('textarea.myclass').val('<%= @text_value.gsub("\r","\\r").gsub("\n","\\n") %>');
```

Hope this corrects you error too.

Answer (score 1):

The best answer I can come up with is to go for a variable. Without testing, this may be answer you are looking for:

```
var newline = "\n";
$('textarea.myclass').val('this is '+newline+' demo');
```

As SilverBlade suggested, maybe a double backslash would do the trick.